# Find count of identical adjacent characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a string:  'AAAAATTT'

I want to write a program that would count each time 2 values are identical. 
So in 'AAAAATTT' it would give a count of:

AA: 4
TT: 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this. This is an O(n) complexity solution which loops through adjacent letters and builds a dictionary based on a condition.

Your output will be a dictionary with keys as repeated letters and values as counts.

The use of `itertools.islice` is to avoid building a new list for the second argument of `zip`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice

x = 'AAAAATTT'

d = defaultdict(int)

for i, j in zip(x, islice(x, 1, None)):
    if i == j:
        d[i+j] += 1
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'AA': 4, 'TT': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'AAAAATTT'
print([(k*2, v - 1) for k, v in Counter(list(s)).items() if v > 1])

#output: [('AA', 4), ('TT', 2)]
```

Comment: This produces the same result for the given example. But this will give `[('AA', 4), ('TT', 2)]`
 for `'ATATATAA'` when the result should be `[('AA', 1)]`.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that requirement. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with *dictionary comprehension* and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'AAAAATTT'

>>> {k: v for k, v in Counter(zip(s, s[1:])).items() if k[0]==k[1]}
{('A', 'A'): 4, ('T', 'T'): 2}
```

Here's another alternative to achieve this using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but this one is not as clean as the above solution *(also will be slow in terms of performance)*.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> {x[0]:len(x) for i,j in groupby(zip(s, s[1:]), lambda y: y[0]==y[1]) for x in (tuple(j),) if i}
{('A', 'A'): 4, ('T', 'T'): 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way may be as following using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
string = 'AAAAATTT'
result = dict(Counter(s1+s2 for s1, s2 in zip(string, string[1:]) if s1==s2))
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'AA': 4, 'TT': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with just `range` method without importing anything :

```
data='AAAAATTT'
count_dict={}
for i in range(0,len(data),1):
    data_x=data[i:i+2]
    if len(data_x)>1:
        if data_x[0] == data_x[1]:

            if data_x not in count_dict:
                count_dict[data_x] = 1
            else:
                count_dict[data_x] += 1



print(count_dict)
```

output:

```
{'TT': 2, 'AA': 4}
```